# Intent extras aren't passed by reference?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a Custom Type object that implements Serializable and i'm able to sucessfully pass this object through my Activities.

Now the situation is this:

On the Activity 1 the CustomObject instance has a String property with the value "A" set and is passed to the Activity 2 as an Extra:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_2.class);
intent.putExtra("CUSTOM_OBJECT", customObjectInstance);

startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

On the Activity 2, i retrieve the CustomObject from the Intent and modify the property value from "A" to "B".

When i press the back button, going from Activity 2 back to Activity 1, the value on the CustomObject's property is "A" again!

I checked the object's hash code and have confirmed that is the same instance on both Activities, and still can't figure it out why this is happening.

**EDIT:**

As requested, about the code where i set the property value, it is as simple as it can be:

On Activity 2:

```
CustomObject obj = (CustomObject) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("CUSTOM_OBJECT");
obj.setProperty("B");
```

Comment: Please post code where you set the property. Java passes *everything* by value. When you pass an "object", you pass a copy of the value of the reference to the object. It's just a long int. Object exists at memory address A. Instance of object in Activity 1 is actually a pointer to address A stored in address B. Activity 2 receives a copy of this pointer stored in address C. None of this answers your question which, since the pointers appear to be the same, is odd.  Note that hash equals does not "guarantee" the same object. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273/index.html

Comment: BTW, please also show how you read the value from extras in Activity 2.

Comment: So what you're saying is that if i need to be able to modify and read the same object's instance from 2 different Activities i must go with a global variable?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of type CustomObject since you are serializing it into and out of extras.  They are two different objects.  Without knowing what you are trying to achieve, it is perhaps best to return the new value via startActivityForResult.

Comment: No.  To create a global to solve this will make the sun stop shining.  What are you trying to achieve?  By the way, .equals() is the test that two objects are the same instance.  Two equal instances must produce the same hash but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Haha. Thanks for the help @Simon. The goal here is that i have a Report with a "Version" on the Activity 1. The Activity 2 is used to retrieve information of that Report from a WebService, based on its Version! Before i go and do that, i check if the version needs to be updated and if does, i change the Version property value.

This Activity 2 starts a whole another process inside my application that in the end, goes back to Activity 1 where i would expect that the changes made on my Report instance would be reflected.

Comment: It is begining to seem to me that since my object reference won't be  "globally" updated for all my Activities using only the Intent, i will override my object in each Activity everytime the "onActivityResult" method is invoked.

That way, when Activity 2 returns to Activity 1, i will override Activity 1's instance with the value from Activity 2. What do you think?

Comment: I was just going to write that ;)  Create the new instance in Activity 2 and serialise it back to Activity 1 via onActivityResult.  Create a new object from that and clone it (or whatever fields you need) back into the original instance.

Comment: @Simon thank you very much! I can't seem to give you a "+" on all your helping me here because they are all comments. I'm new to Stack Overflow as an active user so is that Ok? Shouldn't i reward you with a positive vote / reply or etc.?

Comment: No worries.  Glad to have helped and just hope you end up with a cleaner and easier to maintain solution.  I only give because I also take a lot.  I learned most of the in depth stuff I know from here so giving back is soul food enough.

Answer (score 2):

Intent's extras contain values only. You could handle parameters by reference by extending the Application class and deploying "global" variables.

Althought you express that both object's hash code is the same, i am pretty certain each Activity handles its own set of local variables. In your tests, objects in Activities A and B are independent of each other.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excuse me, but total nonsense.  Java passes everything by value.  An object instance is passed as a copy of the reference pointer value.  In addition, suggesting global variables to solve this issue is totally anti-OOP.  "pretty certain that each Activity handles its own set of variables".  I assume you mean class fields, which if not static, can be handled some other way?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Implementing global variables is an ugly pattern to use and not efficient. What I was trying to prove is that you could have a "global" repository to handle the "same" object.

On the class fields thing, you are right. The Activity's "own set of variables" are its class fields.

Comment: And actually, I was not clear.  You are correct in that you cannot pass objects via extras.  Downvote cancelled.

Comment: I really didn't want to go with global variables for this. Within the scope of my application, it seems wrong to me to turn this object into a global variable. If it isn't possible to send my object's reference to another Activity i probably will use my database to persist it and retrieve its values over and over again on each Activity.

Comment: @Aquanauta Sounds like overkill.  It's rare that multiple activities truly need access to the same object.  It sounds like you're creating some kind of stateful "god" object.  What are you trying to do?  There may be a much cleaner design.

Comment: You could save/update your "god" like values to SharedPreferences and retrieve them everytime you need them.

Comment: The answer to this usually depends on what kind of "state" you're talking about. SharedPreferences writes to a FILE so it should usually be reserved for when you need persistent state across app start/stops. If you don't need persistent state, and what you need to store will fit fine in memory, don't use the filesystem (or SQL or such). Rather, use the Application object (which has a well defined lifecycle and is a perfect place to get/set stuff, though I wouldn't call it "global"), or even use statics (but be careful with statics, usually statics MANAGED by Application is the best bet).

Comment: @CharlieCollins Still dangerous Charlie.  It's all to easy to do something like `new CustomObject(this)` (because you want to access resources) which will create a massive memory leak unless you remember to null out that context when the activity is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling setResult(int) in the Activity returning a result? Here's the docs on starting Activities for results.

> It must always supply a result code, which can be the standard results RESULT_CANCELED, RESULT_OK, or any custom values starting at RESULT_FIRST_USER. In addition, it can optionally return back an Intent containing any additional data it wants. All of this information appears back on the parent's Activity.onActivityResult(), along with the integer identifier it originally supplied.
>
> If a child activity fails for any reason (such as crashing), the parent activity will receive a result with the code RESULT_CANCELED.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities